# Is there a way to run this script in a sequence?

Tags: javascript, liquid

For context I've made a script to assign a localstorage item based on what the user selects, this item may contain "S10" but could also contain many other values, for this example the user has selected "S10"

This has now stored into localstorage.

I have created this script that I have placed in each of the product grid includes, so this script will load multiple times for each product:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const string = localStorage.getItem('MyfitmentList', JSON.stringify(myfitment) );
  const attr = {{ product.metafields['fitment']['fitment'] | json }};

  document.getElementById("fitment").innerHTML = (`${string.includes(attr) ? '✔' : 'not a fit' }`);
}
```

Each product grid also features this container `<div id="fitment"></div>`

The script above loads individually for each product grid card and has it's own seperate values for "attr". If "attr" doesn't contain "S10" (which the user previously selected) then it should show "not a fit", but if the product does contain "S10" then it should show the tick.

The problem I'm having is that this only works for the first script, on the first `<div id="fitment"></div>` container. I can see that each individual script has a different "attr" value which is good, but I don't know why only the first container is populated.

Each script should run individually and populate the "fitment" container within it's own product card. I'm a bit at a loss as to how to do it.

**Also this is on Shopify - Someone below has recommended using a single script with a loop, but in that case how would I retrieve a unique "attr" value each time the script loops? this would still leave the question of how to populate each fitment container with the correct message for each product.**

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: `window.onload =` will allow only a single load handler.

Comment: "*Each product grid also features this container `<div id="fitment"></div>`*" - there's your first problem. Element ids must be unique on a page.

Comment: I tried to make this script getelementbyclassname, but it didn't work with the innerhtml addon to the end, I have no clue why

Comment: "*The script above loads individually for each product grid card*" - don't add multiple scripts that do the same thing. Use a loop over your products in a single script.

Comment: 'window. Onload' will have all of them run at once.  If you want to run things in sequence, i.e. waiting for the other to finish, this won't do it.  They will all run in parallel.  Try running several scripts in one window and watch the network traffic and you'll see they are all running at once.

Comment: The only issue with that is I can only get the product.metafield of a product when the script is running within the product card, as each product card is assigned it's own product. If I move this script outside the product card, then it wouldn't be able to retrieve unique values for "attr"

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how your design is however I would assume your unique id would be from the product that is in the database.   Running them in parallel would be more efficient if you used the product id as the unique identifier and again this isn't my project and I'm unsure of the exact design of your database and system.

Comment: I think if it was to be one script that loops, I'd need to somehow make '"for each product in all collections, if "string" contains "metafield" show a tick, if not show "not a fit"' - but how would that populate each container individually? if all containers have the same ID or class?

Comment: Maybe you need one call that retrieves a collection with the database ids in each object in that collection. Loop over that collection building all of the cards and each object in the list has their own id.

Comment: To answer the first question yes you can run scripts in sequence and tell a function to to wait for another function to return by using a promise to be returned.  I wanted to answer your original question even though this question went off on a tangent.